# Make first item in array appear at the last item

Tags: php, arrays, coordinates, polygon

> Just to note I dont mean to reverse the whole array, just one item which is at the beginning of the array to also appear at the end of the array

I have an example of an array but i dont know how i can make mine to look the same.

I wanted to create a polygon using co-ordinate, and i found an [example on the net](http://assemblysys.com/php-point-in-polygon-algorithm/) that draws the polygon using an array. Below is the array that i found [from the site](http://assemblysys.com/php-point-in-polygon-algorithm/)

```
$polygon = array("-50 30","50 70","100 50","80 10","110 -10","110 -30","-20 -50","-30 -40","10 -10","-10 10","-30 -20","-50 30");
```

Condition is that the first and last array must be the same. And their example is from static numbers.

In my case i have dynamic list of coordinates from the database and i would wish it to generate something like the example given above.

Here is what i have tried but it does not seem to work. **My code now**

```
$query_points = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM ec"); 
$row_points = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_points);

$query_lastpoint = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM ec"
$row_lastpoint = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_lastpoint);

$longitude_last = $row_lastpoint['longitude'];
$latitude_last = $row_lastpoint['latitude'];
$polygon= array();
while ($row_points = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_points))
{
    $longitude_xx = $row_points['longitude'];
    $latitude_yy = $row_points['latitude'];
    $xx_yy = ''.$longitude_xx.' '.$latitude_yy.'';
    $polygon[] = $xx_yy;

}
$polygon[] = "$longitude_last $latitude_last";
```

Its like from the source they use the variable directly as `$polygon` while mine is `$polygon[];` and i cant say `$polygon = $polygon[];`

Any Assistance?

Comment: Your code generates an array `$polygon`, so there is no difference in that aspect. The `$polygon[]` is just a notation to *append* to that array. So is your only remaining question how to add the first element also as last? Or what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is when i use my code it does not work. Since the variable $polygon is used somewhere as it is from the example provided here http://assemblysys.com/php-point-in-polygon-algorithm/. But mine is $polygon[], how do i retain the variable $polygon with the condition

Comment: No, yours is not `$polygon[]`. It is also `$polygon`. What does it mean *does not work*? Which errors?

Comment: No errors but, when experimenting with values the result says 'coordinate not in polygon' while it is supposed to be in polygon. The first example i stated the that it is not my code. it is what i am trying to achieve

Answer (score 4):

You can just append it again, if its already there it wont make a differnce

```
$array[]=  $array[0];
```

otherwise you can do

```
if (end($array) != reset($array)) {  //add the first element here
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php

Comment: finally i would also like to have the variable $array instead of $array[] so that i can use it somewhere.

Comment: @krushiovida, You misunderstand the `[]` notation: it is not a variable, it is an operator on `$array`, which is the variable.

Comment: @trincot so therefore i can still use the variable $array after appending items using $array[] ?

Comment: Yes, `$array[] = 13` is just a notation for `array_push($array, 13)`. See [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).